# Refactor nested ifs with internal if and final else have the same statement

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I would like to refactor a code similar to this one:

```
import os

init_val = 1

existing_file = "test.txt"

if os.path.isfile(existing_file)
    saved_val = read_file(existing_file)

    if saved_val != init_val
        create_file()
else:
    create_file()
```

I want to create the file when it doesn't exist or if the content is different to the initialized value, but I don't want to repeat the `create_file` function twice.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work, just set the `saved_val` as the init value

Then do you're check if it matches just the once.

```
import os

init_val = 1
saved_val = init_val
exists = False
existing_file = "test.txt"


if os.path.isfile(existing_file)
    saved_val = read_file(existing_file)
    exists = True

if saved_val != init_val or not exists:
    create_file()
```

Comment: How does this capture the notion that if the file does not exist, then create it? Remember if the file does not exist then the first statement is not run, hence the value of saved val is not changed. You should create the file. Your solution is not correct

Comment: Very true, i've changed.